# Theano refreshing lock indefinitely

Tags: ubuntu, locking, theano

I'm using Theano 0.8 (from `pip3`), Cuda 8.0 and cuDNN v5 on a `g2` Amazon instance with Ubuntu Server 16.04

When running `theano.test()`, it keeps doing the same action (apparently) indefinitely :

> INFO (theano.gof.compilelock): Refreshing lock
>   /home/ubuntu/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.4--generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid-x86_64-3.5.2-64/lock_dir/lock
>
> INFO (theano.gof.compilelock): Refreshing lock
>   /home/ubuntu/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.4--generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid-x86_64-3.5.2-64/lock_dir/lock
>
> ...

I have no clue what the issue is nor where to start with. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Try `rm -rf ~/.theano/*`, then upgrade to dev version (via github). Make sure theano has write access to home directory. If the problem persists, just submit to github issue tracker.

Comment: @Kh40tiK I'm experiencing the same problem, but I am not finding anything on how to give theano write access to the home directory. Do you have suggestions on how to do this?